# Run Ansible Playbook in one of the VM machines when using Azure Release Pipeline deployment job

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using Azure DevOps Release Pipeline and the Deployment Jobs.

When I run the ansible playbook yaml, all VMs will run the script together.

All VMs are in the same Deployment Group.

Need to define which VM to run the script. Can I select the target VM when using the deployment job?

Ansible command:

```
ansible-playbook -i  provisionAdmin.yml
```

provisionAdmin.yml

```
- hosts: cron
  user: root
  roles:
    - admin
    - analytics
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Need to define which VM to run the script. Can I select the target VM when using the deployment job?

Yes. You can set the tags for the VM machines in the deployment group.

For example:

[image]

When you using the deployment job in release pipeline, you can set the Required tags.

For example:

[image]

In this case, only the VM that meet the tag will be used by the deployment job.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Deployment group jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-group-phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

> You can select specific sets of servers from a deployment group to receive the deployment by specifying the machine tags that you've defined for each server in the deployment group.